# How can I change the styling of hover over menus in ExtJs treelist in micro mode

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, hover, treelist

I'm using Ext js 6.2.1 [Treelist](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.list.Tree.html). Here is the kitchen sink [link](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/examples/kitchensink/#tree-list).

I modified styling of a Extjs treelist items. In Normal mode (micro=false) they look good with different background color, padding etc. But when Tree list is in Micro mode (micro=true) and I hover over the icons- the menu appear with default styling.

How can I apply same/different styling on those menus that come out when I hover over?

Looking at the DOM is puzzling as same unordered list items are being used to be shown as hover over for toolstrip.

Would appreciate any insights on how to do this.

Comment: http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/admin-dashboard/?classic#dashboard

Comment: No. On hovering over icons in micro mode I want the items to appear in same styling as they look in non-micro mode. Working example is available at but how can  we find source code ? :) 
http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/admin-dashboard/?classic#dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the node you want to highlight when hovering over and click 'Inspect Element'. You will see the css classes for that element. Note down the class of the element and in your css file, add the class you found with 'Inspect element' with background-color property.

[image: Fig1]

[image: Fig2]

In CSS,

```
 .x-tree-node-text:hover{background-color:blue !important}
```

The source of most examples are in the extjs folder you downloaded. There is an 'examples' folder which you can refer to.